# Как нарисовать кривую Безье по клику?

Tags: javascript, css3, svg, анимация, svg-animation

У меня есть две точки (`A` и `B`) и кривая Безье, соединяющая их. Анимация рисования линии начинается сразу после загрузки документа.

```css
svg path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: cornflowerblue;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 100;
  stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  animation: path 5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes path {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="300" viewBox="15 15 150 50">

  <circle id="a" cx="26.5" cy="13.2" r="4" fill="cornflowerblue" cursor="pointer"></circle>
  <circle id="b" cx="87.3" cy="23.8" r="4" fill="cornflowerblue" cursor="pointer"></circle>
  
  <text y="15" x="18" fill="cornflowerblue" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.1" font-size="6px">A</text>
  <text y="26" x="92" fill="cornflowerblue" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.1" font-size="6px">B</text>

  <path d="m 26.458333,13.229167 c 2.776366,16.871891 9.790064,18.199908 18.520833,13.229166 L 63.499999,13.229167 C 77.382834,4.1082137 88.663388,0.52362484 87.312499,23.8125 v 0"stroke="cornflowerblue" stroke-width="1" fill="none" id="mPath"></path>

</svg>
```

**Вопрос:** Как мне запустить эту анимацию рисования линии по клику на точку `A`? Интересует подробное описание такой реализации и сама реализация любыми средствами и технологиями, указанными в метках вопроса, а это может быть и `CSS`, и `SMIL SVG`, а также с помощью и `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Pure SVG SMIL

Анимация рисования линии основана на технике уменьшения `stroke-dashoffset` от максимального значения до нуля. Тем самым реализуется анимация роста линии от нуля до полной длины.

- Чтобы посчитать максимальную длину линии, используем метод JS
  `getTotalLength()`

`console.log(p1.getTotalLength());` У нас получилось ~= `91px`

- Далее надо добавить или в стили CSS или прямо в SVG path

```
stroke-dasharray="91" 
 stroke-dashoffset="91"
```

- Далее пишем команду анимации уменьшения stroke-dashoffset до нуля

```
<animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="a.click" dur="4s" to="0" fill="freeze" />
```

, где  `begin="a.click"` - условие запуска анимации по клику на окружности с `id="a"`

```html
<svg width="500" height="300" viewBox="15 15 150 50">

  <circle id="a" cx="26.5" cy="13.2" r="4" fill="cornflowerblue" cursor="pointer"></circle>
  
  <circle id="b" cx="87.3" cy="23.8" r="4" fill="cornflowerblue" cursor="pointer"></circle>
  
  <text y="15" x="18" fill="cornflowerblue" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.1" font-size="6px">A</text>
  <text y="26" x="92" fill="cornflowerblue" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.1" font-size="6px">B</text>

  <path id="p1" stroke-dasharray="91" stroke-dashoffset="91" d="m 26.458333,13.229167 c 2.776366,16.871891 9.790064,18.199908 18.520833,13.229166 L 63.499999,13.229167 C 77.382834,4.1082137 88.663388,0.52362484 87.312499,23.8125 v 0" stroke="cornflowerblue" stroke-width="1" fill="none" id="mPath">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="a.click" dur="4s" to="0" fill="freeze" /> 
  
  </path>

</svg> 
<script>
console.log(p1.getTotalLength());
</script>
```

**Анимация туда-обратно**

Добавляется `values="91;0;0;91;91"` то есть, от мах значения -`91` до `0` и обратно до `0`
Повторяющиеся значения обеспечивают паузы в крайних положениях

```html
<svg width="500" height="300" viewBox="15 15 150 50">

  <circle id="a" cx="26.5" cy="13.2" r="4" fill="cornflowerblue" cursor="pointer"></circle>
  
  <circle id="b" cx="87.3" cy="23.8" r="4" fill="cornflowerblue" cursor="pointer"></circle>
  
  <text y="15" x="18" fill="cornflowerblue" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.1" font-size="6px">A</text>
  <text y="26" x="92" fill="cornflowerblue" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.1" font-size="6px">B</text>

  <path id="p1" stroke-dasharray="91" stroke-dashoffset="91" d="m 26.458333,13.229167 c 2.776366,16.871891 9.790064,18.199908 18.520833,13.229166 L 63.499999,13.229167 C 77.382834,4.1082137 88.663388,0.52362484 87.312499,23.8125 v 0" stroke="cornflowerblue" stroke-width="1" fill="none" id="mPath">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="a.click" dur="4s" values="91;0;0;91;91" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" restart="never"/> 
  </path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 6):

Мы вешаем на элемент с `id=a` обработчик нажатия по нему, дальше мы ищем родительский элемент `svg` и даем ему класс `active`, что и запускает анимацию (в css для `path` который находится в `svg` с классом `active` начинаем анимацию).

```js
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('click', (e) =>
{
  e.target.closest('svg').classList.add('active');
});
```

```css
svg path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: cornflowerblue;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 100;
  stroke-dashoffset: 100;
}

svg.active path
{
  animation: path 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes path {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="300" viewBox="15 15 150 50">

  <circle id="a" cx="26.5" cy="13.2" r="4" fill="cornflowerblue" cursor="pointer"></circle>
  <circle id="b" cx="87.3" cy="23.8" r="4" fill="cornflowerblue" cursor="pointer"></circle>
  
  <text y="15" x="18" fill="cornflowerblue" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.1" font-size="6px">A</text>
  <text y="26" x="92" fill="cornflowerblue" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.1" font-size="6px">B</text>

  <path d="m 26.458333,13.229167 c 2.776366,16.871891 9.790064,18.199908 18.520833,13.229166 L 63.499999,13.229167 C 77.382834,4.1082137 88.663388,0.52362484 87.312499,23.8125 v 0"stroke="cornflowerblue" stroke-width="1" fill="none" id="mPath"></path>

</svg>
```

Comment: Я не разбираюсь в SVG анимациях( Сейчас попробую описать.